# SQL query - Can I query 2 tables that both have an ID field and retrieve both fields?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. Both have fields called "ID".

```
Table 1 has "ID", "Title", "Shift"
Table 2 has "ID", "Table1ID", "Details"
```

I would like to query Table 2 and retrieve all it's details based on an "ID" value but also get the values from Table 1 that relate to the "Table1ID" value.

I've tried this...
`SELECT * FROM Table2 a, Table1 b WHERE a.TableID = b.ID`

This works but only retrieves one tables "ID" field.

I've been playing about with UNION ALL but can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add an alias:

```
SELECT a.ID AID, a.Title, a.Shift, b.ID BID, b.TableID, b.Details 
FROM Table2 a, Table1 b 
WHERE a.TableID = b.ID
```

The above will return `ID` from table A and B as `AID` and `BID` in the result.

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: @Cyclonecode Thanks for the great answer. Is there a way to get the SELECT to get all the fields (without explicitly writing them) and still alias a specific field? My actual Table2 has quite a few fields (I omitted them for clarity with the question)? Thanks again :-)

Comment: @JohnT - Yes, this should work `SELECT A.*, B.*, A.ID AID, B.ID BID FROM Table1 A, Table2 B`

Comment: @JohnT - As others have pointed out this is considered harmful, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful

Comment: @Cyclonecode yep I had read that. I'm going to re-work a lot of the code (including SQL queries) into classes as part of the bigger project. This is just a bit rough and ready to get something usable up and running. I'll make sure I streamline the queries during the second phase. Thanks again for all your help. It's very much appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get the SELECT to get all the fields (without
>   explicitly writing them) and still alias a specific field?

yes its possible but is considered harmful

This is how you would do id

```
SELECT Table1.*,Table2.* from table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.Table1ID;
```

Why I'm saying its harmful see here : [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Proper select should be :

```
SELECT Table1.ID,Table1.Title,Table1.Shift,Table2.ID.Table2.Table1ID,Table2.Details.* from table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.Table1ID;
```